# JavaScript Timer minutes and seconds

Tags: javascript, html, input, timer

I dont know anything about javascript and usually rely on the internet for copy and paste but can do HTML and CSS and I'm working on a focus site for my studies and I have everything down but I would like to add a timer that I can change with minutes and seconds. Ive made a block with 00:00 which represents minutes and seconds that I'd like to change. I have an input for minutes and buttons for "start timer" "clear timer" and "stop timer"

heres my html for the timer:

```
      <button href="#" class="dropdown-btn">Timer</button>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <p>Enter your time in minutes</p>
      <input id="userInputTimer" type="number" value = "0"/> 
    </div>
```

heres the css:

```
.timer-block{
  top: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 200);
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(77, 5, 83);
  font-size: 16px;
  resize: none;
}
div.timer-block{
margin: auto;
position: fixed;
justify-content:center;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

Answer (score -1):

use an input of type "timer"

```
 <button href="#" class="dropdown-btn">Timer</button>
<div class="dropdown-container">
  <p>Enter your time in minutes</p>
  <input id="userInputTimer" type="timer" value = "0"/> 
</div>
```